# Schilling's proof that Cadlag functions can be uniformly approximated in probability by Riemann-Stieltjes sums

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Theorem 16.8 (Schilling: Brownian Motion). Let $f$ be an $\mathscr{F}_t$ adapted right-continuous process with left limits. Then $f \in \mathcal{L}_{T,\text{loc}}^2$. 
For every sequence $(\Pi_k)_{k\ge 1}$ of partitions of $[0,T]$ such that $\lim_{k\to \infty} |\Pi_k|=0$, the Riemann-Stieltjes sums 
$$Y_t^{\Pi_k}:= \sum_{s_j, s_{j+1}\in \Pi_k} f(s_j) (B_{s_{j+1}\wedge t} - B_{s_j \wedge t})$$converge uniformly (on compact $t$-sets) in probability to $f\bullet B_t, t\le T:$ 
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \mathbb{P}\Bigg( \sup_{0\le t\le T} \Bigg|Y_t^{\Pi_k} - \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \Bigg|>\epsilon\Bigg)=0 \;\text{for all} \;\epsilon>0.$$

There are some parts of the proof I'm unclear about.
In the line that starts with "For $0\le s \le \tau_n \wedge T$ the integrand is bounded by $4n$...", why does the integrand converge to $0$, that is, why do we have $\lim_{k\to \infty} f^{\Pi_k}(s) = f(s)$? Is this guaranteed by the right continuity? Why is this guaranteed even when $f$ may have discontinuous points at the left hand? And, why is the last sentence here relevant? That is, why does the author state that the set of discontinuity points is a Lebesgue null set? I don't see what purpose this line serves here.

**Definitions.** [image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, if $s$ is a discontinuity point of $f$, the approximation may not converge to $f(s)$. $f^{\Pi_k}\to f$ point-wise if we redefine $f^{\Pi_k}$ as follows:
$$
f^{\Pi_k}=\sum f(s_j)1_{[s_{j-1},s_j)}
$$
Nevertheless, the original approximation converges to $f$ a.e. (w.r.t Lebesgue measure) because the set of discontinuities is a null set.

Comment: @d.k.o. So the set of discontinuities is a null set is stated here to stress that the original approximation converges to $f$ a.e.?

Comment: It seems that this is the case...